# How do I add cardinality validation to a polars join?

Tags: python-polars

When joining two polars dataframes it can be hard to check whether it is a 1-to-1 join, 1 to many, many to many, many to 1, etc...

In pandas there is a parameter for this (`validate`) in the merge implementation.

```py
validate: str, optional
    If specified, checks if merge is of specified type.
    - “one_to_one” or “1:1”: check if merge keys are unique in both left and right datasets.
    - “one_to_many” or “1:m”: check if merge keys are unique in left dataset.
    - “many_to_one” or “m:1”: check if merge keys are unique in right dataset.
    - “many_to_many” or “m:m”: allowed, but does not result in checks.
```

Is there a way to replicate this checks in Polars? Currently my thinking is I could add a row_number to each dataframe and analyze these columns in the joint dataframe to infer the cardinality of the join - but this seems pretty complex for what might be a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if the join key is unique then you can do

```
df.groupby(join_columns) \
  .agg(count=pl.count()) \
  .unique(subset=join_columns) \
  .filter(pl.col('count')>1)
```

If there are any rows returned then there will be many results returned. If no results are returned then that means it's a "1:" or ":1" depending on which side df you're referring to.

If you to create a row index then you could do something like

```
df_joined= (
    dfL.with_row_count('L_index').join(
    dfR.with_row_count('R_index'),
         on=join_columns
)
```

then you could do group by each to see whatever is relevant to you given the underlying data.

Comment: I like the thinking, but I don't think the last statement is correct. If one L_index gets mapped to 10 R_index (different) due to a repeat in the joining keys that would still result in pl.count().over(['L_index','R_index']) returning 1 for all records.

Comment: @MYK You're right, I just took that out.